# Fit this Paypal's logo and text accordingly as per image

Tags: html, css, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I found a way to copy the Paypal's button style but I could not arrange button properly as it shows in the image file.
And I would like to remove unwanted class ID's that does not need to have for the button style.

[image]

```
<style>
.paypal-button-label-container {
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
white-space: nowrap;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-transform: none;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 14px;
user-select: none;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: none;
vertical-align: top;
cursor: pointer;
overflow: hidden;
height: 45px;
min-height: 30px;
max-height: 55px;
color: #2C2E2F;
background: #ffc439;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
}
</style>

<div role="button" data-button="" data-funding-source="paypal" class="paypal-button paypal-button-number-0 paypal-button-layout-vertical paypal-button-shape-rect paypal-button-number-multiple paypal-button-env-sandbox paypal-button-color-gold paypal-button-text-color-black paypal-logo-color-blue" tabindex="0" aria-label="PayPal"><div class="paypal-button-label-container"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" data-v-6a159a85="" alt="" aria-label="PP" class="paypal-logo paypal-logo-pp paypal-logo-color-blue"><span class="paypal-button-space"> </span><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" data-v-6a159a85="" alt="" aria-label="PayPal" class="paypal-logo paypal-logo-paypal paypal-logo-color-blue"><span class="paypal-button-text" optional=""> Buy Now</span></div><div class="paypal-button-spinner"></div></div>
```

Comment: You'll need to copy the CSS style for each of the class IDs and put it in the relevant place

Comment: The above style is what I got.

Comment: There are additional styles.